# angular-google-maps not updating markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am using the library [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) however it does not appear to be updating the markers when I push or remove markers from the markers array which is demonstrated in the plnker below. The console shows a new marker has been added while this is not reflected on the map.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Si5tANvbU8Fro14OC4ny?p=preview

```
$scope.addPlace = function() {

       $scope.places.push({
        id: 3,
        latitude: 42,
        longitude: -79
      });

      console.log($scope.places);

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set  `modelsbyref` to  `false` in `ui-gmap-markers` directives

```
 <ui-gmap-markers models="places" coords="'self'" modelsbyref="false">  

   </ui-gmap-markers>
```

Comment: It's called using ng-click on the button in plnkr